# load some script if another unavailable

Tags: javascript, html

I have some script attached via `<script src="..."></script>` in index html file to be used after its load. But for some reason my script may not be available some time. When it occurs client should load another script and exec it also after its load instead of the first one.

How can i do that?

P.S. I've no another ways except using 2 different files

P.S.2 Availability of file can only be checked on client, the reason is not in the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject the scripts dynamically, you can listen for the `error` event on the primary script. If that event fires, inject the secondary script. Here's an example:

```js
const addScript = src => {
  const script = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
  script.src = src;
  return script;
};
const script1 = addScript('doesntexist');
script1.addEventListener('error', () => {
  console.log('Failed...');
  const script2 = addScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
  script2.onload = () => {
    console.log('jQuery loaded:', typeof $);
  };
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using this method you can chain your fallbacks too.

Comment: That's beautiful, so btw is it legal to use short `script1.onerror` instead of `script1.addEventListener('error'...`?

Comment: @IPShow Yes, that works, but using `addEventListener` is usually better, because then any numbers of listeners will be added. Using `on-` anything, in contrast, can break when multiple parts of the code both try to add a listener; in such a case, only one listener can exist at a time.